# It's election time!

Tags: code-golf

## It's time... to count the votes!

Today there are local elections in my entire country. Here, the number of seats for each party is decided using the [D'Hondt method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method). Your goal is to implement a program or function that will decide how many seats each party gets, in the shortest amount of bytes.

For this method there are a fixed number of seats to distribute, and it's done like so:

1. Every party is assigned a variable number, which starts at the number of votes it got.
2. Then the first seat is given to the party who has the biggest value in their variable and then that value for that party becomes their total number of votes divided by `1+seats`, rounded down, where `seats` is the number of seats it already has (so after getting the first, their votes are divided by 2, and by 3 after getting the second seat).
3. After that the parties votes are compared again. The process continues until all the seats have been assigned.

If the highest number is a tie between two or more parties, it is resolved randomly (It has to be random, it can't just be the first of the two in the list).

### Input

You will receive a number `N`, which will indicate the number of seats available, and a list of the votes each party received, in whatever format you prefer. Example:

```
25
12984,7716,13009,4045,1741,1013
```

### Output

You should output a list of the seats each party got. In the example above it would be something like

```
8,5,9,2,1,0
```

They should be in the same order as the parties in the input.

### Examples

```
5
3,6,1

outputs: 2,3,0
```

---

```
135
1116259,498124,524707,471681,359705,275007,126435

outputs: 45,20,21,19,14,11,5
```

### Bonus

**-20% bonus** if take the parties name as input and give them in the output, like for example:

```
25
cio:12984,pcc:7716,irc:13009,icb:4045,cub:1741,bb:1013

outputs

cio:8
pcc:5
irc:9
icb:2
cub:1
bb:0
```

Comment: I feel we already did something like this

Comment: I couldn't find anything alike in the search... But if you find anything I will change it or remove the question, no problem!

Comment: @rcrmn There is something wrong with your last example. Maybe you meant 153 total seats instead of 135.

Comment: @Tyilo Right! I wrote it wrong in my test program and copied the answers without double-checking. It's fixed now. Thank you!

Comment: @rcrmn You also might want to add all the possible outputs that a program should be able to produce from `5` `2,3,1`.

Comment: Does this method use integer of floating point division?

Comment: Integer arithmetic, or floating point rounding down, I updated it to clarify.

Comment: Regarding the output for the bonus: Do we have to display the parties in this particular order? Also, do we have to display parties with 0 seats?

Comment: Finally, can we assume that the parties' names contain only letters?

Comment: Thanks @Jakube , that was a problem with the program I used to calculate, which returned the output ordered in seats with labels. Dennis you can return it in any order, since the label works as an identifyer. You can assume it only has letters if it's easier for you.

Comment: Splendid, thanks. `bb:0` has to be displayed though, yes?

Comment: Yes, all parties should be displayed.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12466/preferential-voting

Comment: @Oxinabox How are they similar, apart from being voting systems?

Comment: They are similar as they are both voting systems, with a kind of (interesting) reallocation component. It may be the question that edc65 was thinking of. (Sorry, I accidentally typed possible duplicate, I mistyped.)

Comment: Oh okay, I was just surprised because I couldn't see where the duplication was. Thanks for the link though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CJam, <s>35.2</s> <s>28.8</s> <s>28.0</s> 26.4

```
q2*~,m*mr{~)f/1=~}$<:(f{1$e=1\tp}
```

This full program is 33 bytes long and qualifies for the bonus.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q2*~%2Cm*mr%7B~)f%2F1%3D~%7D%24%3C%3A(f%7B1%24e%3D1%5Ctp%7D&input=%5B%5B%22cio%22%2012984%5D%20%5B%22pcc%22%207716%5D%20%5B%22irc%22%2013009%5D%20%5B%22icb%22%204045%5D%20%5B%22cub%22%201741%5D%20%5B%22bb%22%201013%5D%5D%0A25).

#### Example run

```
$ cjam seats <<< '[["cio"12984]["pcc"7716]["irc"13009]["icb"4045]["cub"1741]["bb"1013]]25'
["cio" 8]
["pcc" 5]
["irc" 9]
["icb" 2]
["cub" 1]
["bb" 0]
```

#### How it works

```
q2*~   e# Repeat the input from STDIN twice. Evaluate.
       e# STACK: Array seats Array seats
,      e# Range: seats -> [0 ... seats-1]
m*     e# Take the cartesian product of the array from the input and the range.
mr     e# Shuffle the array. This makes sure tie breakers are randomized.
{      e# Sort by the following key:
  ~    e#     Dump: [["party" votes] number] -> ["party" votes] number
  f/   e#     Divide each: ["party" votes] number -> ["party"/number votes/number]
  1=   e#     Select: ["party"/number votes/number] -> votes/number
  ~    e#     Bitwise NOT.
}$     e#
<      e# Keep only the elements that correspond to seats.
:(     e# Shift each array.
       e# RESULT: S := [[number] ["party" votes] [number] ["party" votes] ...]
f{     e# For each A := ["party" votes]:
       e#     Push S.
  1$   e#     Push a copy of A.
  e=   e#     Count the occurrences of A in S.
  1\t  e#     Replace the vote count with the number of occurrences.
  p    e#     Print.
}      e#
```

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, 36 bytes - 20% = 28.8

```
J<_hCo/@eCQhNheN.S*UQUvzvz.e,b/JkhCQ
```

This qualifies for the bonus.

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%3C_hCo%2F%40eCQhNheN.S*UQUvzvz.e%2Cb%2FJkhCQ&input=25%0A%5B%22cio%22%2C12984%5D%2C+%5B%22pcc%22%2C7716%5D%2C+%5B%22irc%22%2C13009%5D%2C+%5B%22icb%22%2C4045%5D%2C+%5B%22cub%22%2C1741%5D%2C+%5B%22bb%22%2C1013%5D&debug=0) or [Test harness](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=+QzFdc.z2AzQ%2Chdved*%5C-yTztP%60Qpk%22output%3A+%22+++J%3C_hCo%2F%40eCQhNheN.S*UQUvzvz.e%2Cb%2FJkhCQ&input=Test+Cases%3A%0A%22%22%0A25%0A%5B%22cio%22%2C+12984%5D%2C+%5B%22pcc%22%2C+7716%5D%2C+%5B%22irc%22%2C+13009%5D%2C+%5B%22icb%22%2C+4045%5D%2C+%5B%22cub%22%2C+1741%5D%2C+%5B%22bb%22%2C+1013%5D%0A5%0A%5B%22a%22%2C+3%5D%2C+%5B%22b%22%2C+6%5D%2C+%5B%22c%22%2C+1%5D%0A135%0A%5B%22a%22%2C+1116259%5D%2C+%5B%22b%22%2C+498124%5D%2C+%5B%22c%22%2C+524707%5D%2C+%5B%22d%22%2C+471681%5D%2C+%5B%22e%22%2C+359705%5D%2C+%5B%22f%22%2C+275007%5D%2C+%5B%22g%22%2C+126435%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
                                       implicit: z = 1st input (as string)
                                                 Q = 2nd input (evaluated)

                      vz               evaluate z (#seats)
                     U                 generate the list [0,1,...,seats-1]
                   UQ                  generate the list [0,1,...,len(Q)-1]
                  *                    Cartesian product of these lists
                .S                     shuffle (necessary for break ties randomly)
     o                                 order these tuples N by:
        eCQ                               list of votes
       @   hN                             take the N[0]th vote count
      /      heN                          and divide by N[1]+1
   hC                                  extract the party index of the tuples
  _                                    reverse the list
 <                      vz             take the first #seats elements
J                                      and store them in J

                          .e     hCQ   enumerated map over the names of the parties
                                       (k = index, b = name):
                            ,             generate the pair:
                             b/Jk            name, J.count(k)
                                       print implicitely
```

Comment: `J` is unnecessary. You can get rid of it and save 2 bytes.

Comment: Also, if you swap `z` and `Q`, and then save `Cvz` to `K`, you can save another byte.

Comment: @isaacg Nope, it is very important. Because of the shuffling the expression might yield different results in `.e` and it messes up the counting.

Comment: Actually, the second tip doesn't work either, sorry, because I missed the `UQ`.

Comment: I did it without the party names in 24 bytes, substantially based off of your program. Should I put it as a comment here, or as a separate answer?

Comment: @isaacg Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, 210 bytes

```
v=(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)=>{d=Object.assign({},b),c={};for(g in b)c[g]=0;for(;a--;)e=0,f=Object.keys(d),f.forEach(a=>e=d[a]>e?d[a]:e),f=f.filter(a=>d[a]===e),f=f[~~(Math.random()*f.length)],d[f]=b[f]/-~++c[f];return c}
```

Notes:

- Requires a modern browser/engine with support for ES6. Tested in Firefox.
- Uses the very important `/-~++` operator :)

Example usage:

```
v(25, {cio:12984,pcc:7716,irc:13009,icb:4045,cub:1741,bb:1013})
```

Comment: It's not necessary to declare all of your variables as arguments.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to avoid polluting the global scope of possible

Comment: JS golf is all about polluting the gobal scope :)

Comment: I've golfed your method down to 168 bytes. Sorry for mangling the variable names. `F=(N,X)=>{for(t=[o={}],[t[o[j]=0,j]=X[j]for(j in X)];N--;t[z=y[new Date%y.length]]=X[z]/-~++o[z])m=0,y=[(m=m<t[j]?t[j]:m,j)for(j in X)],y=y.filter(j=>t[j]==m);return o}`

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - 54 bytes

```
AGZQ=kZK*]0lZVGJhOfqeTh.MZZ.e(kb)Z XJK1 XZJ/@kJ+@KJ1;K
```

Input format (stdin):

```
[25,[12984,7716,13009,4045,1741,1013]]
```

Output format (stdout):

```
[8, 5, 9, 2, 1, 0]
```

Variables used:

```
G = total number of seats
K = array of seats currently assigned to each party
k = number of votes for each party
Z = k/(K+1)
J = which party should have the next seat
```

Comment: Use `vz` and `Q` instead of `G` and `Z`. This way you will save the assignment with `A`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 110

```
#!perl -pa
$n=pop@F;@x=map
0,@F;/a/,$x[$'/$n]++for(sort{$b-$a}map{map{($'/$_|0).rand.a.$i++}//..$n}@F)[0..$n-1];$_="@x"
```

Input space separated with the seat count last.

Try [me](http://ideone.com/pXiSjq).